Slim-Select plugin not working well with bootstrap 5.3 dark mode
Slim-Select plugin does not work well with bootstrap 5.3 dark mode, the plugin defaults to light mode even when the app is using dark mode. This also affects the input element search-box or search-bar as you cannot see the text you're typing into it, when using dark mode. I would appreciate any help you can afford me in resolving this issue.

I found an alternative plugin that is well maintained with the required behaviour called UseBootstrapSelect.
